# Breaking down a ReadProcessMemory function that reads multiple offsets

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to figure out the most logical step by step way of reading offsets, here is the code im currently working on.

```
    DWORD BaseOFFSET = 0x000000;
    DWORD address2 = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(BaseOFFSET + 0x50),0, sizeof(DWORD), 0); //50 doors down in baseoffset
    DWORD address3 = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(address2 + 0x0500),0, sizeof(DWORD), 0); // address 3 is address2 + another 500 doors down the line
    DWORD address4 = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(address3 + 0x140),0, sizeof(DWORD), 0); // and so on...
    DWORD address5 = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(address4 + 0x100), 0, sizeof(DWORD), 0); //Final offset is stored in address5
```

Because I know a float is stored in the final address I will use this to cout the value thats in the address

```
float* Data = (float*)(&address5);
    if (Data != nullptr)
        Sleep(2000);
    cout << *Data << std::endl;
```

I have sleep (2000) in there because its a long loop checking the value in the address to see if it changes, and depends on the change I will do different things. Code compiles and runs fine but the value returned is wrong, I'm getting 0s when I cout in the loop.

Comment: You might want to refer to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for ReadProcessMemory.  It doesn't return the value read, you're using it improperly.

Comment: I'm surprised the code isn't crashing. The output parameter is not optional, and you're passing NULL.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using `ReadProcessMemory` wrong. It returns 0 for failure, 1 for success. You're getting zeroes because it failed, probably because you passed a null (0) for the output pointer, which is not optional.

Second, you can't use pointers from another process directly (as you try to do with `*Data` in your example). You need to call `ReadProcessMemory` with the foreign pointer you obtained to read the pointed-to data in the context of the other process.